# iOS Facebook Popup Window is going everything about:blank

Tags: ios, facebook, redirect, popupwindow

I have a Problem. On Android, Chrome Mobile Devices when i open my website from the Facebook APP my popup is working. e(Popunder)... But when i open the same on my IPhone, iOS, it redirects automatic to about:blank!

Does anyone know this problem?

Regards

Regina

EDIT:

Okay.

1) My Website has got an Popunder script on it from Adcash. 2) When i open the site on iOS, Android, or Desktop the pounder is working very fine. 3) When i open the site on Android, Chrome, etc. from the Facebook inApp is working fine.

But !!!

When i open the site from iOS(IPhone) from the Facebook inApp it will redirect to about:blank empty page...

Do you understand know the problem? I tried many weeks to solve this issue but i don't know why it is so.

Comment: not getting exactly  your problem .please give some more information

Comment: please add this in your question , mess edit your question,remove that from answer place

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this issue.

On iOS only, and on either Facebook or Twitter's in-app browser

- Tap on an article/link
- Within the article, tap on a link that goes to a different domain and has a `target=_blank` attribute
- The window is now white with the url set to `about:blank`

This issue is cross-product and not only Facebook's end.

The only method to address this issue was to change the target attribute from `_blank` to `_self`.

I'm trying to see if other people have had this issue or even addressed anywhere else, but this post is the closest I've come across to seeing it addressed.